# How to use express-uploadfiles?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I want to print the name of a file to the console, but it gives me an error:
when I post the path of my server with the file

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')`

my code is:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");

// SETTINGS
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

// MIDDLEWARES
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`${req.method} - ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

// ROUTES
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
    const file = req.files.file;
    console.log(file.name);
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get("port")}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the fileUpload middlewere. Its the middlewere that adds the files to the request method.

```
app.use(fileUpload())
```

Add this before the upload handler, in the same way you use the bodyParser middlewere.

To upload files you also need to make sure that the html form uses

```
encType="multipart/form-data"
```

You can check out the documentation: https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload

It also has basic code examples: https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: My actual code https://pastebin.com/8wMMm0g9

Comment: my html códe: https://pastebin.com/APv2k1ix

Comment: Edited the answer, you're missing multipart/form-data in your html.